# ¿como puedo crear un json?

Tags: json, visual-basic

Necesito crear un json en visual basic, lo que no entiendo es como lo armo ya que al ir asignándole valores a las variables me dice instancia del objeto no referenciada.
Esto lo lo estoy creando atraves de las clases que me creo visual studio para simplificar un poco el trabajo pero no entiendo la sintaxis de VB para poder ir instanciando las variables de cada clase

```
Private Sub BtnPagarMercado_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPagarMercado.Click
   


    Dim ventaMercado As New Rootobject
    Dim items As New Item


    ventaMercado.external_reference = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
    ventaMercado.total_amount = 9000

    ventaMercado.items.sku_number = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
    ventaMercado.items.category = "Tiendas 1"
    ventaMercado.items.title = "Producto1"
    ventaMercado.items.description = "Producto"
    ventaMercado.items.quantity = 3
    ventaMercado.items.unit_measure = "unit"
    ventaMercado.items.unit_price = 3000
    ventaMercado.items.total_amount = 9000

    ventaMercado.taxes.value = 100
    ventaMercado.taxes.type = "IVA"

    Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ventaMercado)


End Sub
```

Las clases que me dio visual studio

```
Public Class Rootobject
 Public Property external_reference As String
 Public Property total_amount As Integer
 Public Property items() As Item
 Public Property taxes() As Tax
 Public Property notification_url As String
 Public Property title As String
 Public Property description As String
End Class

Public Class Item
 Public Property sku_number As String
 Public Property category As String
 Public Property title As String
 Public Property description As String
 Public Property quantity As Integer
 Public Property unit_measure As String
 Public Property unit_price As Integer
 Public Property total_amount As Integer
End Class

Public Class Tax
 Public Property value As Integer
 Public Property type As String
End Class
```

Comment: ventaMercado.items es nulo! te lo dice el error. Donde estas inicializando ese items??? no me digas que afuera, porque afuera es otro objeto....

Comment: esta dentro del clase Rootobject

Comment: ahi esta definido.. donde esta creado?? donde esta el new dentro de la clase?=???